# Why is `sudo pkill -HUP -f "nginx: master process"` returning code 129 and no output

Tags: process, sudo, kill

I'm trying to trigger a reload of the Nginx master process by using `pkill` and `sudo`.

The server reloads fine, but I was just curious if anyone knows why the command `sudo pkill -HUP -f "nginx: master process"` returns code 129?

```
# Running as root
$ pkill -HUP -f "nginx: master process"
$ echo $?

# Output is as expected:
0

# Running as a user (sudo is set to not prompt for a password)
% sudo pkill -HUP -f "nginx: master process
% echo $?

# Output is weird (considering sudo should be passing along the return
#                  code of the command it is executing):
129
```

Running on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS running on EC2 ... surprisingly Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS running on a physical computer (not installed using cloud images) runs fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, when the shell returns a status code above 128, it means that the process was killed by a signal. Subtract 128 to get the signal number. Your kill command was killed by signal 1, which is HUP.

`pkill` takes care never to kill itself. But it matched its parent, the `sudo` process.

There are several ways to avoid this:

- Use `pkill -x` to consider only exact matches and not substrings (recommended if possible, this is the best way to avoid spurious matches).
- Don't use the `-f` option.
- (Last resort) Write a pattern that doesn't match itself, e.g. `"[n]ginx: master process"`.

Comment: Awesome idea ... I used pkill -x and just used the regex patter "^nginx: master process.*$" which worked like a charm! Thank you!
End result: `sudo pkill -HUP -x -f "^nginx: master process.*$"`

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` returns 129 because `pkill` is sending the HUP signal to `sudo`.  This is because `sudo`'s command line matches the string you gave to `pkill` with `-f`.  A process terminated by a signal exits with code 128 + the signal number.  HUP is signal number 1, hence exit code 129.